# Android Studio 3.1.1 apk download size increased by more than double

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk

Recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.1 and 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' following which the signed release apk size has more than doubled on all platforms. Analyze APK shows the "download size" to match that of the earlier releases, but the actual APK size on disk is the actual "size on disk / installed size".
I am using JNI libraries including my own for the project with minSDK=15. The only other change I had to make was remove armeabi platform build as forced with the new update.

[image: Comparison with the previous release a week back.]

Any possible reason attributable to the sudden jump in APK download size?

UPDATE:

I was able to upgrade my minSDK to 23 and change extractNativeLibs=true and get back to the same behavior as before. Is this behavior possible maintain while retaining minSDK to 15 (or atleast 19)?

[image: APK size retained as before with extractNativeLibs=true]

Comment: You're using JNI. Perhaps the new tooling that comes with AS 3.1.1 targets a broader range of hardware platforms. That could explain the larger .apk size for the new platforms, but it's hard to know without details of your build configurations.

Comment: The only platforms I am building (and have not changed) are - arm v7, arm v8, x86, x64 and universal installer.
As can be seen in the background APK analyzer, the download size shown for the new APK is same as before, but the size on disk is the uncompressed size. 
I can't switch to android:extractNativeLibs=”true” since that support starts from only SDK 23 and my minSDK is 15.
Would you require any specific configuration detail to make a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found in my EDIT, despite the warning that extractNativeLibs supports from v23 onwards, I was able to set to false and still retain the minSDK to 15.
The APK sizes are similar to previous releases (compressed native libraries). This was though a change in behavior in AS 3.1.1/3.1.2 release, and hence caught by surprise.